# Issues with synchronously downloading a file in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

With multiple methods to download the file and write it synchronously in my local application (currently using a module called `download-file-sync`), I am having issues with the file written using `writeFileSync`.

Here is my code:

```
var downloadFileSync = require('download-file-sync');
fs.writeFileSync("twc.mp4", downloadFileSync(sourceURLEncoded));
```

Now this technically writes *something*, and opening the file in Notepad++ shows at least the start of the file is identical to the same file downloaded via Chrome, with the same amount of lines. However, the file size is around doubled:

[image: Downloaded MP4 files. Chrome download is 5,723 KB. Node download is 10,339 KB.]

The Node download will not play, while the Chrome download does.

How am I able to achieve a successful synchronous file download in Node?

Comment: Just an idea, but you might try downloading a *small* file (like, one that's only a few characters) and then compare the text content of each, just to have an idea of what the difference is

Comment: Try checking the length of the data that you are saving.

Comment: you used an npm module for 4 lines of code? my guess is it has something to do with the encoding - which in that NPM module is hard coded to `{encoding: 'utf8'}` for mp4 file, I would think you'd want binary encoding

Comment: Perhaps one file is still encoded and it needs to be decoded.  All, `download-file-sync` does is fire up a child process to run CURL.

Comment: Don't use `download-file-sync`. It returns a UTF8-encoded string from raw audio data which isn't going to preserve the original bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that [download-file-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/download-file-sync) calls curl and encodes the result as a string when you want "pure" bytes.

If the string isn't valid UTF-8 some characters may be expanded resulting in a different size and content than the original binary file.

To fix you can simply replace the module with the code it uses and make a new function where you use `buffer` (the default) for encoding:

```
function downloadFileSync(url) {
  return require('child_process')
    .execFileSync('curl', ['--silent', '-L', url]); // remove options {encoding: 'utf8'}
}
```

And try with that instead.

Comment: The encoding of JavaScript strings plays no role in the encoding of the saved file. The only relevant encodings are the one specified in `download-file-sync` and the default encoding for `fs.writeFileSync()` when the `data` argument is a string, which is also UTF8.